# setInitialText method in SLComposeViewController iOS 8.3 does not show text in Facebook sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

The code snippet below is the callback for an on screen button. The Facebook sheet appears but contains no text. However, if you replace `SLServiceTypeFacebook` with `SLServiceTypeTwitter` it does show the initial text. I am using XCode 6.3.1 and iOS 8.3 on an iPhone 6. Thank you in advance.

```
-(IBAction)facebookButton:(id)sender
{
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        NSString* facebookText = @"Awesome App";
        SLComposeViewController *fbPostSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [fbPostSheet setInitialText:facebookText];
        [self presentViewController:fbPostSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else{
         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Unable to Connect to Facebook"
                              message:@"Make sure your device has an internet connection and you have your Facebook account setup in the Settings App"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

Comment: The initial text being removed from the Facebook dialog has become an issue since Facebook's latest update. You are not alone.

Comment: Facing same problem in ios8.2 also and found no solution yet.

Comment: Same problem here i have 8.0

Answer (score 15):

If you delete the Facebook app on the device, the initial text will appear.

Comment: Deleting the Facebook app on my iPhone does allow the inititial text to appear. However, I cannot ask my users to delete their facebook app so they can post their score on Facebook.

Comment: You may want to have a custom UI for your case. Please remind that you have to submit your app for Facebook review. I had also googled this issue but sadly i did not find any documentations about this..

Comment: I'm having the same issue in my game. But, to be clear, @Chrisswong, are you saying that we have to register our apps with Facebook to fix this issue?

Comment: Making your own UI for Facebook sharing allows you provide any initial texts for Facebook sharing. However, you must register on [Facebook developer site](http://developer.faceobok.com) , enable "publish_actions" permission and submit iOS simulator build for Facebook review so that you can go live with Facebook sharing and share to public. You must be aware of this [POLICY](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill) for the initial text you provided.

Comment: @Chrisswong as I understand from Policy link you provided, Facebook now reject using of "prefill". So making your own compose controller will not solve the problem. I guess that this is a reason of change in iOS 8.3.

Comment: @JohnTracid In fact one of my app is using custom UI for Facebook sharing. However, i pre-filled the text inside a textview so that user can edit  the text and finally Facebook review approved this. From i understand the "pre-fill" is something that the user is not able to edit and it shows in the shared content.

Comment: Use Facebook share dialog

Comment: @Chrisswong can you share the link of your application so that we get an idea of creating custom dialog. I am sucked with the same since few weeks. Thanks

Comment: @ManiKhalil no worries! it was pretty long ago so most of us aware this issues and provide other alternatives to the users.

Answer (score 1):

It actually works if you set the text inside the completion handler:

```
NSString* facebookText = @"Awesome App";
SLComposeViewController *fbPostSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
//[fbPostSheet setInitialText:facebookText];
[self presentViewController:fbPostSheet animated:YES completion:^
{
    [fbPostSheet setInitialText:facebookText];
}];
```